# Option menu not working with theme ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-theme

I have created an application which has a `RecyclerView` and each item has an option menu, which will show the popup to share. Everything is working fine but when I try to click on the option menu it crashes. I am getting a weird error. I google it and it seems like there is something wrong with my theme. I tried many solutions available on the internet but none of them working for me.

Here is my theme:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/about_us_link_text_color</item>
</style>
```

This is my Adapter class

```
 holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu(context,holder.buttonViewOption);
            popUp.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
            popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.share:
                           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.setType("text/plain");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,news.get(position).getUrl());
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"check out this site");
                            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"share"));
                            break;
                        case R.id.save:
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popUp.show();
        }
    });
```

option_menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:title="Share" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:title="Save" />
</menu>
```

The error I am getting is :

```
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x1d/d=0xffff4081 a=3 r=0x7f0c001a}
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:705)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6890)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:7071)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:446)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:386)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:385)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:502)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuAdapter.getView(MenuAdapter.java:93) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopup.measureIndividualMenuWidth(MenuPopup.java:160) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.tryShow(StandardMenuPopup.java:153) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.StandardMenuPopup.show(StandardMenuPopup.java:187) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.showPopup(MenuPopupHelper.java:290) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:175) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:141) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:233) 
                                                                         at com.kotlin.whatshappening.activity.adapter.NewsAdapter$2.onClick(NewsAdapter.java:142) 
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post `R.menu.option_menu` file?

Comment: Try `new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), ...)`

Comment: @azizbekian thanks a lot man you really save my day..

Comment: Fine! Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu(context, holder.buttonViewOption);
```

Perform:

```
PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), holder.buttonViewOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
popUp.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu, popUp.getMenu());
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: why are you returning false inside onMenuItemClick()? Change it to true. and check if it is still throwing error?

Answer (score 0):

First create a method in you adapter class like the following.

```
 private void showPopup(View view, String url) {
     PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activityContext, view);
     MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, popup.getMenu());
     popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.share:
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setType("text/plain");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,url);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"check out this site");
                        activityContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"share"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.save:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
     popup.show();
 }
```

And in your *onBindViewHolder* method call the above function,

```
holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showPopup(view, news.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getUrl());
    }
});
```